# How does potential energy relate to kinetic energy on a rollercoaster?

Tags: energy, energy-conservation, conservation-laws, potential-energy, kinetic-theory

This is appearantly how the potential and kinetic energy are in the different positions of the rollercoaster, if I am not mistaking.

[image]

However I don't understand why the total energy is energy and how you can have negative potential energy. Could someone explain the reason for the negative values?

Comment: Did you take the representation with bars from a book or it is your own thinking of the problem? (if there is a problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values presented in the bar chart aren't really energies, they are **changes in energy**.

Using the frame of reference shown ($y$-axis) the kinetic ($K$) and potential ($U$) energies at point 1 are:

$$K_1=0$$
$$U_1=mgy$$

Assuming no friction or air-drag acts on the car, then Conservation of Energy applies, so:

$$K+U=\text{constant}=mgy$$

When the car reaches point 2, then with $v_2$ the speed of the car at point 2:

$$K_2=\frac{mv_2^2}{2}=mgy$$
$$U_2=0$$

The value for potential energy shown in the bar chart for point 2 however is the **change** in $U$:

$$\Delta U=U_2-U_1=-mgy$$

Work out the same for point 3 (which is still *lower* than point 1) and you'll see that $\Delta U=U_3-U_1<0$, as shown in the bar chart.

The exercise shows how on a roller coaster potential energy $U$ is constantly being converted to kinetic energy $K$ and vice versa, depending on the height of the car.

Comment: If the bar were really supposed to mean changes in energy, what is the meaning of the bar for total energy? The change between what positions?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of a roller coaster's ascent is to build up potential energy. The higher a roller coaster cart goes up, the more gravity can pull down and give the roller coaster more kinetic energy. Whenever a roller coaster cart goes down, this potential energy transforms into kinetic energy. When the coaster cart  goes up one of the smaller hills and follows the initial hill lift, its kinetic energy changes back into potential energy. Like this there is constant changes in energy throughout roller coasters.